# can someone please explain the meaning of semblance?

Tags: difference

I have tried to learn the meaning of the word 'semblance' looking up in the dictionaries and on the internet.
But i don't think i am getting the meaning.

I am very confused about the meaning of semblance.

If you could give me any examples that'd be great.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a sentence containing the word *semblance* or a definition of the word that you do not understand?

Comment: 1. It gives you back some semblance of control.
2. Along the way, for your own sanity as well as that of your employees and customers, it’s nice to have some semblance of consistency.
3. She bared her teeth in a semblance of a smile.
4. He dropped all semblance of dignity and rushed down the street after her.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In those examples, *semblance of X* means *something that resembles X*.  When you add "some" to the noun, *some semblance*, it means *something that resembles X, if only just a little, or to a very small degree".

**It's better to have at the very least a cubicle, if you cannot have your own office with a door you can shut. A cubicle provides *some semblance* of privacy.**

Comment: that was useful  thnks

Comment: @needhelp On this site, the up arrow next to a post can be clicked to indicate that you find an answer useful, and as the person who asked this question you have the option to mark an answer as accepted (if you find that it answers your question fully). These mechanisms feed into a system of [reputation](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) and [priviledges](http://ell.stackexchange.com/privileges). You can read more about voting [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). I’ve just written this to explain why you won’t see “thanks!” comments, and may have yours deleted.